# How to send the XML encoded data to the Rest API when it has &amp; as it takes the data after "&" as new post parameter?

Tags: php, xml, rest

I am trying to send the XML data to a Rest PHP API, XML data has "&" in it - when the data reaches the server the data after "&" is taken as new param. Is it the right behaviour? One solution is to send the data as binary octet-stream but I am curious to know if sending the data as application/xml with &amp has this behaviour.

```
   Server side code to accept post:
if (isset($_POST['xmldata'])) {
$data = $_POST['xmldata'];
  } else {
 //See if data is coming in file.
 $data = ''
}

Data to be sent to server via rest client:
  <ENVELOPE>
  <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Abc &amp; Co</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
  <BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Abc &amp; Co</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
  </ENVELOPE>
```

Data received as server looks like:

```
  Array
 (
   [data] => <ENVELOPE>
  <PARTYLEDGERNAME>Abc 
   [amp;_Co</PARTYLEDGERNAME>
 ______<BASICBASEPARTYNAME>Abc_] => 
[amp;_Co</BASICBASEPARTYNAME>
 </ENVELOPE>] => 
 )
```

Comment: You should definitely  send the xml data encoded as `application/xml`. And access it via `file_get_contents("php://input");` on php side...

Comment: Btw post the client-side code if you need more help...

Comment: @JuniusRendel - thanks for the reply. 

For Client, I was testing it via the Rest API client (RestClient - Firefox) and dumped the post variable to check the data. 
Method : POST
Content-type: application/xml
Body: XML data to be sent to server given above.

Comment: Ok so the main solution is to use `file_get_contents('php://input')`